# Highstock tick interval not showing

Tags: highcharts, intervals

I have a problem with showing on a Chart the tickinterval.

Please look at this example:

```
$(function() {
    var usdeur = [[Date.UTC(2003,8,24),0.8],
                  [Date.UTC(2003,8,25),0.8]]
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 0.01
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/adrianCC/QqTgY/7/

If I have the same value I do not have any intervals in the chart on the vertical axis.

Can it be possible to add some intervals?

Thank you!

Comment: You can set min/max value, or use tickPositions http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositions